# PHP: how to check if the server is running locally

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to check if the server is running locally
using this code:
"if (strstr ($ _SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost.../'))"
I get a negative answer meaning it is not a local runner
But in fact he is yes running locally
why is it happening?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` show? It should show the host name without the protocol. 

Also why is there a space between `http:` and `//`? But it shouldn't include the protocol anyway

Comment: Again. What does `var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])` show?

Comment: And does it contain "localhost:4000"?

Comment: it indeed show only "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

ServerName is ServerName, literally.

> http://**localhost**/anylink/here

> https://**anothersitewithport.com**:666/the-port-is-not-a-server-name

In this case, ServerName only matchs to localhost or anothersitewithport.com

The protocol (http/https/ftp etc...) and Port (80/443/4000 etc...) will not show in this var.

Comment: You are right about the protocol. But if I test this on a local server I do see the port. E.g. "127.0.0.1:8080"

Comment: Many thanks to Uriel
I have written
if (strstr ($ _ SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost'))
And it works